# xcopy doesn't work with relative path and environment variable

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I'm executing the following command:

```
xcopy /Y /R "%VS140COMNTOOLS%..\IDE\CommonExtensions\Platform\DiagnosticsHub\x86\dbghelp.dll" binaries\msvcr\
```

This command results in the following:

> File not found - dbghelp.dll
>   0 File(s) copied

`echo %VS140COMNTOOLS%` yields the following - I merely expanded the environment variable:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\

Meanwhile, the following command works:

```
 xcopy /R /Y "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\..\IDE\CommonExtensions\Platform\DiagnosticsHub\x86\dbghelp.dll" binaries\msvcr\
```

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\Tools\..\IDE\CommonExtensions\Platform\DiagnosticsHub\x86\dbghelp.dll
>   1 File(s) copied

What's the problem?

Comment: Is the batch-file consisting of only this one line or is there more behind it?

Comment: @geisterfurz007: I'm currently testing in the command line, so there's nothing more. Just this one `xcopy`.

Comment: @geisterfurz007: well spotted. The first line is correct, I've edited the second.

Comment: Is the content of the environment variable: 1. terminated with a `\ `symbol? 2. included within `""` on its own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xcopy /Y /R "%VS140COMNTOOLS%..\IDE\CommonExtensions\Platform\DiagnosticsHub\x86\dbghelp.dll" binaries\msvcr\
```

The command line above fails with the error message below in 4 cases:

> File not found - dbghelp.dll
>   0 File(s) copied

1. The folder path assigned to environment variable `VS140COMNTOOLS` does not end with a backslash.
   This possible cause of error is obviously not the case here as `echo %VS140COMNTOOLS%` prints the folder path with a backslash at end.
2. The environment variable has the string value:
   `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\`
   But this is not the case here as otherwise `echo %VS140COMNTOOLS%` would print that string.
3. The folder path assigned to environment variable `VS140COMNTOOLS` has 1 or more trailing spaces/tabs.
4. The folder path assigned to environment variable `VS140COMNTOOLS` starts with 1 or more leading spaces/tabs.

For the second and third cause of error it would help to run `echo "%VS140COMNTOOLS%"` and look if the output is:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\ "

or

> " C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\"

Using syntax `set variable=value` can easily result in getting the value with trailing spaces/tabs assigned to the environment variable resulting on usage in errors like this one. The solution is using `set "variable=value"` as explained in detail in answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)

For completeness a definition of the environment variable `VS140COMNTOOLS` with the command line

```
set VS140COMNTOOLS="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\"
```

with first double quote after equal sign instead of left to variable name and no trailing spaces/tabs would result in execution the command line:

```
xcopy /Y /R ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\"..\IDE\CommonExtensions\Platform\DiagnosticsHub\x86\dbghelp.dll" binaries\msvcr\
```

But this command line would result in the error message:

> Invalid number of parameters

So already double quoted folder path can be also excluded as possible cause of the error.

BTW: The help of `xcopy` output by running in a command prompt window `xcopy /?` lists the optional parameters after source and target parameters. It is of course possible to specify first `/R /Y` and then source file and target folder, but it is in general advisable to use the syntax as suggested by help of command.

Comment: Great answer, but it doesn't actually solve the problem, sadly. `echo "echo %VS140COMNTOOLS%"` produces `"echo C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\"`.

Comment: That's very strange. I suggest next to use free tool [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor) from Sysinterals (Microsoft) with filter set to __Path contains dbghelp.dll__ then __Include__, run the command __xcopy__ with the environment variable reference and look in log of Process Monitor on recorded file system activities.

Comment: Well this was fun. Just so happens that I'm mostly using PowerShell as my every-day terminal, and my command fails there. But it works in cmd.exe. This is on Windows 10.